# How do we remove mystical [X] from text? Image included

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars-decode

Wordpress has placed an uncalled for character on one of our page's text. We have a few hundred pages, and this only occurs on one. In the paragraph's text, between the words 'Music' and 'Students', WordPress has placed a [X] character. It is not in the visual or text views, and only appears on the actual page. It cannot be copied nor is there an extra space in the code. In essence there is no extra character between the two words, aside from the space.

What caused this and how can it be removed?

[image: X error in text]

If permissable, I can provide the URL containing the error.

Comment: I see you already found an answer. But what browser was that happening in? I remember a similar issue in Chrome on Android.

Comment: For reference, it was Chrome; causation was likely original user imported from Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by deleting the sentence and retyping it. The issue did not replicate. My best thought was that the import user imported text via Word.

Comment: The cause is most likely that the text was originally copy-pasted from something like a Word Document or elsewhere. There is more than one kind of "space" character in the world, and an extra hidden one in the text could cause what you saw here. Best to type simple text in a simple text editor, and not use big editors like Word to write out posts and such. :)

Comment: You are correct, it was text bulk imported using word documents. Not my choice, I wouldn't import from word personally.

Comment: If you find this happening a lot, copy and paste from Word into Notepad first, then copy from Notepad to elsewhere. Pasting into Notepad causes it to become plain text and remove the weird formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your custom font is missing for this char. Try use "eraser" tool in editor to format styles for this text.